# Link stylesheets to Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been looking at [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial06/) and now have a stylesheet in */static/styles/*.

The problem is that the template doesn't pick this up:

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/stylesheet.css" />
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
```

Do I need something in my settings file? Where am I going wrong?

My project structure is:

```
project
    - manage.py
    - project
        - static
        - templates
        -  __init__
        - etc..
```

**EDIT**
My urls.py now looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from bible import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'bible.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^verses/', views.search),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And this is my view.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from bible.models import TBbe, TBookNames


def search(request):
    errors = []
    if 'b' in request.GET:
        if 'c' in request.GET:
            if 'v' in request.GET:
                book = request.GET['b']
                chapter = request.GET['c']
                verse = request.GET['v']
                verses = TBbe.objects.filter(b=book, c=chapter, v=verse)
                book = TBookNames.objects.filter(id=book)
                books = TBookNames.objects.all;
                return render(request, 'verses.html', {'verses': verses, 'book': book, 'books':   books})
            else:
                raise Http404()
        else:
            raise Http404()
    else:
        books = TBookNames.objects.all;
        return render(request, 'search_verses.html', {'books': books})
```

Comment: `{% static 'styles/css/stylesheet.css' %}` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get a 404 when I try and get to .../static/css/stylesheet.css

Comment: will that be because you have your stylesheet in `/static/styles` and you're trying to find the file in `/static/css`?

Comment: Afraid not, I changed it to /static/css to fit with @Burhan Khalid's answer

Comment: have you then set the `STATIC_ROOT`?

Comment: In my settings.py file I have "STATIC_URL = '/static/' STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'"

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` should be the absolute path like `/the/path/to/your/static` without the last forward slash

Comment: Like this? "STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/jont/Documents/django/bible/bible/static'"

Comment: yes, please post if this solves your problem. the 404 status means they cannot locate your stylesheet file

Comment: Neither solution seems to find the file. It is under that location but still returning a 404 unfortunately.

Comment: try this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/stylesheet.css" %}">`
and remember like other suggest, load a tag on top with `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: Still 404 I'm afraid. I would have thought the extra double quotes would become an issue but it didn't fall over, just did the same thing as before.

Comment: um... are we complicate things on this simple question? Try one more time: put this `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top before `<html>` tag

Comment: are you running under `DEBUG=True` or `DEBUG=False`?
or I'm under an impression you're missing url config, check:
`urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: I have Debug set to true, please see my edits that show urls.py and views.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seemed to be that I needed the following code in my settings.py file:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

which is the same as the code to reference my templates folder. If you put the static files at the same level, it should work. This is also providing you have followed the advice of everyone on here, importing static etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have your static directory defined in your settings.py
2. Add the following to your template where needed:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% static 'css/mystyle.css' %}
```

Comment: I have "STATIC_URL = '/static/'" in my settings file. Is that enough?

Comment: If you have your stylesheet in static/styles you should be using something like {% static 'styles/mycss.css'  %}. Use the template tag and check what is being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add below line to your settings.py along with load static and static rules plus debug mode true. No need to add anything into urls.py file. Django will automatically find static folder inside each app folder. This I found from the documents https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS.

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, you should have a leading slash:

```
href="/static/css/stylesheet.css"
```

but really you should use the static tag:

```
{% load static %}
...
href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now using the static tag and no luck. Please read the comments under my question for more information.